# How do I check an iOS device's battery health?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, battery

I am looking for a way to check the current health of a battery for iOS devices, similar to how [coconutBattery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/) works for OS X.

How can I check the battery health for an iOS device?

Comment: This is now part of ios 11  (finally)

Comment: Now that this is an official part of iOS 11, [bmike's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/320993/72620) be marked as the accepted answer.

Comment: This is still only built-in for iPhones as of iOS 15 - for iPads, you still need an app, whether on the iPad or a connected computer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From a computer you could install [coconutBattery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/), from version 3.2 it supports downloading and monitoring iOS device's battery health.

[image: coconutBattery showing iOS battery health]

Another option (partially working on iOS 11, i'm expecting it to be removed, because it uses restricted API) is [Battery Life](https://www.batterylifeapp.com).

**Old answer, reported not working on iOS 8 and above:** Found an easier way. Jailbreak your phone and install `BatteryInfo Lite`. It's a free, ad-sponsored application. Tested on iPhone 3gs, iPhone 4 and iPad and it works. BatteryInfo Lite provides the following useful information:

- Temperature
- Capacity (current, design, maximum)
- Charge Level
- Cycle count
- Voltage
- BootVoltage
- Battery Serial number
- Model number

Here is a screenshot of the application running on my iPhone 4.

[image: BatteryInfo Lite screenshot]

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on iOS 8.1.1 - does anyone have an alternative?

Comment: @Colin try coconutBattery 3.2 - works like a charm.

Comment: @mspasov If the old application no longer works, the updated recommendation should be moved to the start of your answer.

Answer (score 14):

There are apps that you can use to assess battery health, but I recommend a Mac/PC app called [iBackupBot](http://www.icopybot.com/itunes-backup-manager.htm). Tether your device (non-jailbroken works) to your computer, navigate to the lower left window pane, select the device, and click the link for ‘More Informations’. The top portion of the resulting window will look something like this:

[image: iBackupBot iPad2,6 Battery]

From [Check iPad iPhone battery charge cycle count without jailbreaking - iCopyBot](http://www.icopybot.com/blog/check-ipad-iphone-battery-charge-cycle-count-without-jailbreaking.htm):

> 1. Connect your iPad, iPhone or iPod Touch to computer, then launch iBackupBot.
> 2. Select your iPad, iPhone or iPod Touch in Devices window, then click More Informations in right side window
> 3. iBackupBot will pop up a window to show many informations about your iPad, iPhone or iPod Touch, include the battery charge cycle
>      count, battery campacity and more

The best iOS app I have used to provide this info is [BatteryLogger Plus](http://tinkertank.eu/batterylogger/plus/). However, it requires a jailbreak. Non-JB apps seem to provide optimal operating information, but not cycle count information. This may be a function of App Store limitations, which is why BatteryLogger Plus is a Cydia store app instead.

Answer (score 7):

Apple has an official tool as part of iOS 11.3 for iPhones in the settings app:

- https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208387

iPadOS shows a graph of recent usage but doesn’t offer a health analysis.

watchOS devices show health of the battery and also offer optimized charging.

[image]

Many people had strong opinions on [power throttling in iOS and excellent technical details are in this link.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310722/)

Tap the settings app and then scroll up the list so you can see and select the Battery item (above Privacy and below Emergency SOS) and then select Battery Health:

[image]

> [image]

Since the feature was Beta, it has been quite accurate on several devices I have tested with various aged batteries and overall performance that I subjectively / objectively measure.

Here is a device that’s almost three years old

[image: iPhone 11 battery health]

Comment: And since this is part of the official OS - it should put an end to all the attempts for apps on the store to duplicate this now built in feature. Most of them were pulled very quickly after they enter the store should they make it past review in the first place.

Comment: This is still only built-in for iPhones as of iOS 15 - for iPads, you still need an app, whether on the iPad or a connected computer.

Comment: Indeed @RichVel I have updated this with watchOS and more details on how this feature has worked since beta on iPhones. Thanks for the nudge to update this!

Answer (score 1):

This app does not require a jailbreak: [batterylifeapp.com](http://batterylifeapp.com)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found a regular App Store app (doesn't require jailbreak) that does all of this: [Battery Health](https://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id1048805552?pt=117722868&ct=ad_se&mt=8).

It's not free, but for what it's worth...

[image]
[image]

**Update:** This app has been removed by Apple.

Comment: Hmm, how did they manage to get it past App Store reviews..

Comment: Not available in Dutch Store.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, many apps can check the battery status, I use Battery Doctor.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please add a link to the app you suggest in your response and if you are in any way related to it, please disclose it. Thanks!

Comment: In my humble opinion Battery Doctor does absolutely nothing. Tells me nothing I didn't already know, shows no meaningful information. Just a bunch of pretty graphics and animations. I don't get how they get 5,000 5 star reviews...