# Is the iPhone 5 slowed down by Apple? If so how to revert?

Tags: iphone, ios

Given that Apple slows down your phones to save battery, how do I speed my iPhone 5 back up now I have replaced the battery myself?

Comment: I’ve edited out the cliam second question. One question per question is best here. Let’s deal with power management if any on iPhone 5 first.

Comment: why all the downvotes, explain yourselves

Comment: I would say that "Apple slows down your phones to save battery" is wrong entirely. There's a kernel of truth, but wouldn't it be better stated "If Apple detects a battery that can't push peak current - some phones on some iOS levels will reduce performance to prevent sudden shut down when the battery is between 50 and 0% overall charge"

Comment: Also - the general policy is to never ever explain a down vote - even if you aren't the person. Best to ask on [meta] if anyone feels the voting on this is wrong. That tends to get the most seasoned people to give you advice and/or correct the voting if needed once the question gets edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The iPhone 5 is not affected by the slowdown, only the 6 & higher - see [How can I verify if Apple is slowing down my phone because of an old battery?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310722/how-can-i-verify-if-apple-is-slowing-down-my-phone-because-of-an-old-battery)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Tetsujin's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/310998/239027), even if your phone were affected, if you've replaced the battery, then your phone would be working at full speed again. The throttling is based on the phone's internal diagnostics of the battery condition. Assuming the new battery you put in is equal to or better than the original battery, then the phone would automatically un-throttle.

Comment: I see, but it also frequently freezes at random intervals. Maybe a factory reset will fix that